# Create a table inside of tr tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an html table, `<tbody>` of it is generated with angular `ng-repeat`. Here is my html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="car in carList | filter:tableFilter" ng-click="activeRow = car.name">
        <td><a target="_blank" href="{{car.carLink}}">{{car.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{car.review}}</td>
        <td>{{car.rating}}</td>
        <td>{{car.fiveStarPercent}}</td>
        <td>{{car.recommended}}</td>
        <td>{{car.price}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="activeRow==car.name">
        <td>{{car.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to replace `<td>{{car.name}}</td>` with the table that will show only when you click on some row.

But if I just go and replace `<td>{{car.name}}</td>` on the table I need, my main table will no longer create extra rows when you click.

**So, is it possible to put a table inside of a `<tr>` tag? If yes, then what is the right way to do it?**

Comment: yes, it is possible, though it should go inside of a td in the tr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `colspan` and `rowspan` for this purpose https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do it like this:

```
<table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>
```

ie, you can add a full table inside the td

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zWMUU/206/)**